# Get Kernel Architecture Android

Tags: android, android-studio

How to get information of kernel version and kernel architecture in android using android studio?
For kernel version I can get with :

```
System.getProperty("os.version")
```

but how with kernel architecture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the version of the Linux kernel using Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234574/how-to-get-the-version-of-the-linux-kernel-using-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private String getFormattedKernelVersion() {
    String procVersionStr;

    try {
        procVersionStr = readLine(FILENAME_PROC_VERSION);

        final String PROC_VERSION_REGEX =
            "\\w+\\s+" + /* ignore: Linux */
            "\\w+\\s+" + /* ignore: version */
            "([^\\s]+)\\s+" + /* group 1: 2.6.22-omap1 */
            "\\(([^\\s@]+(?:@[^\\s.]+)?)[^)]*\\)\\s+" + /* group 2: (xxxxxx@xxxxx.constant) */
            "\\((?:[^(]*\\([^)]*\\))?[^)]*\\)\\s+" + /* ignore: (gcc ..) */
            "([^\\s]+)\\s+" + /* group 3: #26 */
            "(?:PREEMPT\\s+)?" + /* ignore: PREEMPT (optional) */
            "(.+)"; /* group 4: date */

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PROC_VERSION_REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(procVersionStr);

        if (!m.matches()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Regex did not match on /proc/version: " + procVersionStr);
            return "Unavailable";
        } else if (m.groupCount() < 4) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Regex match on /proc/version only returned " + m.groupCount()
                    + " groups");
            return "Unavailable";
        } else {
            return (new StringBuilder(m.group(1)).append("\n").append(
                    m.group(2)).append(" ").append(m.group(3)).append("\n")
                    .append(m.group(4))).toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,
            "IO Exception when getting kernel version for Device Info screen",
            e);

        return "Unavailable";
    }
}
```